# Как вывести значение объекта через шаблонизатор

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Есть код:

```js
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        rates: await getRates('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
    });
});
```

В `rates` возвращается объект.

В шаблонизаторе есть строчка:

```html
<%= rates.RUB %>
```

В html вместо результата вижу `[object Object]`.

Как я могу вывести значение объекта через шаблонизатор?

Я пробовал выводить так:

```html
<%- rates.RUB %>
```

Не помогло.

Comment: у тебя в rates.RUB действительно объект, выведи rates.RUB.sell, например

Comment: @nörbörnën, спасибо, это решает мою проблему. Вопрос был немного в другом: как вывести объект как строку, но я уже с этим разобрался: JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давай я тебе покажу стартовую песочницу.

У меня она имеет такую файловую структуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const transport = require('./transport');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views')); // эта строка тебе не понадобится

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    const rates = await transport.get('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker');
    res.render('index', {
        rates
    });
});

app.listen(3003, 'localhost');
```

### transport.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
 
exports.get = async function(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return res.json();
};
```

### views/index.ejs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <% Object.keys(rates).forEach((currency) => { %>
            <h1><%- currency %></h1>
            <dl class="row m-4">
            <% Object.keys(rates[currency]).forEach((key) => { %>
                <dt class="col-sm-3"><%- key %></dt>
                <dd class="col-sm-9"><%- rates[currency][key] %></dd>                
            <%}) %>
            </dl>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

То, что я вижу в браузере после запуска приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]